# Problem with using \only command in beamer

Tags: beamer

I have created the following frame in beamer:

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Adjacency Matrix}
    \vspace{1em}
    \only<1>{
    \begin{block}{What is an adjacency matrix?}
    \vspace{0.5em}
     An adjacency matrix is a square matrix used to represent a finite graph.
    \end{block}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    For a graph with $\mathbold{\abs{V}}$ vertices, an adjacency matrix is a $\mathbold{\abs{V} \times \abs{V}}$ matrix.
    \\\vspace{1em}
    If the edge between vertex $\mathbold{i}$ and vertex $\mathbold{j}$ is denoted by $\mathbold{V_{i,j}}$ then there are two possibilities.
    }

   % ........

\end{frame}
```

Now inside this frame, I want several slides. For that I wrote the following code:

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
        \begin{enumerate}
        \only<2>{
            \item Unweighted Graph
                \vspace{1em}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Matrix of 0s and 1s where in row $\mathbold{i}$ and column $\mathbold{j}$ is $1$ iff the edge $\mathbold{(i,j)}$ is in the graph
                \end{itemize}

                \[      \Scale[1]{
                        V_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
                                    1 & if ~ edge(i,j) ~ exists \\
                                    0 & otherwise
                                \end{cases}
                        }
                \]
            }
            \only<3>{
            \item Weighted Graph
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Edge weight is placed in $\mathbold{V_{i,j}}$ entry if there is an edge and a special value (perhaps \textit{null} to indicate absence of an edge. 
                \end{itemize}
            }
        \end{enumerate}
```

I want the first item (Unweighted graph,enumerated 1) to show on slide 2 and the second item (Weighted graph,enumerated 2) to show on slide 3. But when I run this, on sharelatex, it shows the following error:

```
 main.tex, line 106
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table.

 Learn more Was this hint helpful? Yes / No
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.106 \end{frame}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Currently, it's looking like this:

[image]

[image]

Both unweighted and weighted graph are enumerated 1.

What am I doing wrong?

**The full code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%

% Swap the definition of \abs* and \norm*, so that \abs
% and \norm resizes the size of the brackets, and the 
% starred version does not.
\makeatletter
\let\oldabs\abs
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
%
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother


\title[About Beamer]{Graph Representation Techniques}
\author[Author A and Author B]{Tanjim Bin Faruk (1505082) \\ Tanjim Munir (1505083) }
\institute{}
\date{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi
    \vfill%
    \centering % NEW
    \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi
    \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \vspace*{10mm}
    \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
    \vspace*{20mm} % NEW
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
    \vfill
    \vspace*{1mm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title}{
%  \raggedright%
    \centering
  \linespread{1.0}%
  \inserttitle%
  \par%
  \vspace*{0.5em}
}


\begin{document}
\metroset{block = fill}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Adjacency Matrix}
    \vspace{1em}
    \only<1>{
    \begin{block}{What is an adjacency matrix?}
    \vspace{0.5em}
     An adjacency matrix is a square matrix used to represent a finite graph.
    \end{block}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    For a graph with $\mathbold{\abs{V}}$ vertices, an adjacency matrix is a $\mathbold{\abs{V} \times \abs{V}}$ matrix.
    \\\vspace{1em}
    If the edge between vertex $\mathbold{i}$ and vertex $\mathbold{j}$ is denoted by $\mathbold{V_{i,j}}$ then there are two possibilities.
    }

    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
        \begin{enumerate}
        \only<2>{
            \item Unweighted Graph
                \vspace{1em}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Matrix of 0s and 1s where in row $\mathbold{i}$ and column $\mathbold{j}$ is $1$ iff the edge $\mathbold{(i,j)}$ is in the graph
                \end{itemize}

                \[      \Scale[1]{
                        V_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
                                    1 & if ~ edge(i,j) ~ exists \\
                                    0 & otherwise
                                \end{cases}
                        }
                \]
            }
            \only<3>{
            \item Weighted Graph
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Edge weight is placed in $\mathbold{V_{i,j}}$ entry if there is an edge and a special value (perhaps \textit{null} to indicate absence of an edge. 
                \end{itemize}
            }
        \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that on the first overlay the `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}` is already present but not a single item - which is not allowed.

So you have to make sure, that there is no empty enumeration on the first frame.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Adjacency Matrix}
    \vspace{1em}
    \only<1>{
    \begin{block}{What is an adjacency matrix?}
    \vspace{0.5em}
     An adjacency matrix is a square matrix used to represent a finite graph.
    \end{block}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    For a graph with $\mathbold{\abs{V}}$ vertices, an adjacency matrix is a $\mathbold{\abs{V} \times \abs{V}}$ matrix.
    \\\vspace{1em}
    If the edge between vertex $\mathbold{i}$ and vertex $\mathbold{j}$ is denoted by $\mathbold{V_{i,j}}$ then there are two possibilities.
    }

        \only<2-3>{
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
        \begin{enumerate}
        \only<2>{
            \item Unweighted Graph
                \vspace{1em}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Matrix of 0s and 1s where in row $\mathbold{i}$ and column $\mathbold{j}$ is $1$ iff the edge $\mathbold{(i,j)}$ is in the graph
                \end{itemize}

                \[      \Scale[1]{
                        V_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
                                    1 & if ~ edge(i,j) ~ exists \\
                                    0 & otherwise
                                \end{cases}
                        }
                \]
            }
            \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
            \only<3>{
            \item Weighted Graph
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Edge weight is placed in $\mathbold{V_{i,j}}$ entry if there is an edge and a special value (perhaps \textit{null} to indicate absence of an edge. 
                \end{itemize}
            }
        \end{enumerate}
            }

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not however solve my problem. I used the \only command because it would technically erase the content and place the content on that slot. So, I want the weighted graph point on the same spot as unweighted graph but on different slides. Using, ``\item<2>`` and then ``\item<3>`` places weighted edge on the lower part of the page.  See the image : https://imgur.com/a/UEiyW2m

Comment: @Robur_131 see updated answer - however if you only want a single item per slide, I would not bother with all the problems and simply use separate frames (if you need the same frame number, there is an option for that)